# SQL Concat function only when row count less than number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. One is a list of quarters and the other is a list of years. I need to write a query to return the years, and append the word "partial" at the end of the years that contain less than 4 quarters.

An example of a couple of rows from the year table:

```
YearName | YearUUID
2015     | 15C33
2016     | 16C33
```

An example of the quarters table:

```
QuarterNumber | StartDate  | YearUUID
1             | 2015-01-01 | 15C33
2             | 2015-03-01 | 15C33
3             | 2015-06-01 | 15C33
4             | 2015-09-01 | 15C33
1             | 2016-01-01 | 16C33
2             | 2016-03-01 | 16C33
```

See that in the above example, 2016 will be a partial year. So my query results should be as follows:

```
YearsList 
2015             
2016 - Partial
```

I've used the Concat function before, but never with a condition such as this. Without knowing how to condition it, I created the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(Years.YearName, ' - Partial') as YearsList 
FROM dbo.Quarters Quarters,
     dbo.Years Years
WHERE Quarters.YearUuid = Years.YearUuid
      AND Quarters.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND Quarters.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
ORDER BY YearsList ASC;
```

This gives me a list of all of the years, but appends 'Partial' to every single one of them. There is obviously no condition in there. How do I incorporate a condition into that query so that I get full years (years that contain 4 quarters) without 'Partial' appended on the end, while also maintaining the DISTINCT and maintaining the ORDER BY, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `GROUP BY` and a `CASE WHEN` construct:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(Quarters.QuarterNumber) < 4
          THEN CONCAT(Years.YearName, ' - Partial') 
          ELSE CAST(Years.YearName AS varchar)
       END as YearsList
FROM dbo.Quarters Quarters,
     dbo.Years Years
WHERE Quarters.YearUuid = Years.YearUuid
      AND Quarters.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND Quarters.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
GROUP BY Years.YearName
ORDER BY Years.YearName ASC;
```

Comment: I get the following error: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2011 - Partial' to data type int.

Comment: Wait, that sounds like an SQL Server error message. Your question is tagged with Oracle. Are you not on Oracle?

Comment: Sorry, yes I am using SQL Server Management Studio. I am adding this to the tags

Comment: I just checked this, but it should run well on SQL Server. Are you including this query in some other query, or reading it in some application? Could you give some context? The query as provided here does not need to convert anything to `int` so there must be an external reason.

Comment: I am not including it in another query. Also not reading it in some application. I am directly running the query in SQL Server Management Studio. The only change from your text that I made, is I changed the table names, etc. to match the table names in my database...

Comment: `SELECT CASE
           WHEN COUNT(bcq.BroadcastQuarterNbr) < 4
           THEN CONCAT(bcy.BroadcastCalendarYear, ' - Partial')
           ELSE bcy.BroadcastCalendarYear
       END as YearsList
FROM AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarQuarter bcq,
     AudienceProjections.dbo.BroadcastCalendarYear bcy
WHERE bcq.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid = bcy.BroadcastCalendarYearUuid
      AND bcq.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'
      AND bcq.BroadcastQuarterType = 'STANDARD'
GROUP BY bcy.BroadcastCalendarYear
ORDER BY bcy.BroadcastCalendarYear ASC;`

Comment: Ok so I commented out the following line `AND bcq.ActiveStatus = 'ACTIVE'`, then I no longer received the error message. However, the CASE WHEN THEN did not work. It printed out all of the years, without the text "Partial"

Comment: I think the problem is related to the data type of `bcy.BroadcastCalendarYear`. In your question you had  `YearName` instead, which strongly suggests a `varchar` data type, but now that I see the real name, it seems like it is an `int` type. So in that case you must wrap it in a `CAST(bcy.BroadcastCalendarYear AS varchar)`.

Comment: One more question. How would I use that query to ONLY grab the current year?

Comment: Add in the `WHERE` clause something like `AND bcy.BroadcastCalendarYear = YEAR(GETDATE())`